# How would you write mathematically that a random variable follows some unknown distribution?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, notation

For example, if I had a random variable X and knew it followed a normal distribution, I might write:

$X \sim N(5, 10)$

What would I write if I'm trying to say that the distribution is unknown?

$X \in \Omega$

Is that correct? It doesn't feel right.

Comment: If you have previously defined or described $\Omega$ as a set of distributions that would be perfectly fine and clear.  Because conventionally "$\Omega$" is already used to refer to a sample space, though, that might confuse an experienced statistical audience.

Comment: I would just say that $X$ is a random variable.

Comment: Unless there's some special reason you need to use mathematical notation, I would suggest to use narration instead: "Let $X$ be a random variable with [density $\delta$/cdf $F$/positive support/...]".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The notation I tend to see is something like $X\sim F_X$ to denote that $X$ is a random variable with $F_X$ as its CDF. I have seen people try to be brief and just write $X\sim F$, but this could mislead others into thinking that $X$ has an $F$ distribution, when that could be far from the case.

Comment: Just to nitpick, we have books that go for $X\sim P_X$ too.

Answer (score 2):

Standard notation is $X\sim F$ or $X\sim F(x).$.

Update: the latter notation, while common shorthand, could be misunderstood since $F(x)$ is a probability.

Comment: I can't explain the downvote, but it made me look closely at this answer and I can't help noticing that "$X\sim F(x)$" is a mathematical solecism: $F$ might be a distribution function, but then $x$ must be a possible value of $X$ and therefore "$F(x)$" refers to a *probability* -- a single number.

Comment: My, the nitpicking is *strong* with this community.

Comment: @Stephan Nitpicking maybe--but that kind of abuse of notation is the source of plenty of misconceptions IMHO.

Comment: @whuber that's why I started with F , and only as second option F(x).  You could also write X~F(y). Hence why included it for clarity ( even though technically it's a probability).  I doubt anyone who is familiar with probability/stats to the degree of sample spaces has a misconception (!) By F vs F(x) notation. I ll be more precise next time

Comment: @whuber: I'm all with you on this, I *have* tried to get "nitpicker in chief" as a job title. I just found the five upvotes to your comment versus the zero net votes on the answer a trifle remarkable...

Comment: I appreciate your clarification, Georg.  I would even upvote your answer if you only were to mention in it that the latter notation, although perhaps common, could be misunderstood (and I would recommend avoiding it).